# How to change listview's items' color change

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

```
movieRating = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMovieRating);
        ArrayList<String> mov_rating = new ArrayList<String>();
        mov_rating.add("G");
        mov_rating.add("PG");
        mov_rating.add("PG-13");
        mov_rating.add("R");
        mov_rating.add("NC17");
        mov_rating.add("NR");
        mov_rating.add("Not Rated");
        mov_rating.add("Pending");
        ArrayAdapter<String> movieRatingadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mov_rating);
        movieRating.setAdapter(movieRatingadapter);
```

I want to change textcolor of listitem.It is white but I need to change it into black.

```
<ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvMovieRating"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fl2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="513dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#fff" >
            </ListView>
```

Comment: You'll have to replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` by a layout (xml) you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
       movieRating = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMovieRating);
    ArrayList<String> mov_rating = new ArrayList<String>();
    mov_rating.add("G");
    mov_rating.add("PG");
    mov_rating.add("PG-13");
    mov_rating.add("R");
    mov_rating.add("NC17");
    mov_rating.add("NR");
    mov_rating.add("Not Rated");
    mov_rating.add("Pending");
    ArrayAdapter<String> movieRatingadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view,R.id.textView1, mov_rating);
    movieRating.setAdapter(movieRatingadapter);
```

R.layout.list_view

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Confirm Batsman Dismissal"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Main Activity listView

```
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMovieRating"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fl2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="513dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#fff" >
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace android.R.simple_list_item_1 by a custom xml:

// in mylist_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

// in your code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> movieRatingadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylist_item, mov_rating);
```